# Preview image of website is wrong when sending link via facebook

Tags: wordpress

I have a wordpress website, and for some reason when I send the link over facebook the image associated with the link is the default Wordpress 2017 home image:

[image]

I checked the home page of the website and the media library and that image is nowhere to be found! Is there anyway to change it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook generally uses the OpenGraph-data if you provide it (well, not always, there are exceptions, but let's keep it simple). If you have a meta tag like

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://www.example.org/myimage.png"/>
```

Facebook will consider that to be the image you want to show.
To increase the likelihood of them honoring your wish, add

```
<meta property="og:image:width" content="$imagewidth"/>
<meta property="og:image:height" content="$imageheight"/>
```

(replace the content attribute with the actual image dimensions, of course) and try to use the [recommended image sizes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/best-practices/).

Many SEO plugins will allow you to add OpenGraph markup without getting your hands dirty and editing your templates.

Comment: The `<meta>` tag does not use or require a closing slash.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'll have to try and remember that (and see whether I can change my habit of typing `/>` automatically).